# Image mask module for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to use WooCommerce product variations with an image of T-shirt, and another image, like a mask, with the T-shirt design. I try to search module but nothing found.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add another image of product variation very easily from the backend setting 
of the product there is an option to add particular attribute variations image.
[image]